# adding and editing a new row in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am adding a new row at the top of an existing ag-grid with this code

```
function addRow() {
  let lastrow = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(gridOptions.api.getLastDisplayedRow());
 gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({add:[lastrow.data], addIndex:0});
}
```

this works.
I then want to edit the cells which I do by double clicking on each cell.
Every time I press enter, it calls the grid callback

```
onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
  const rowNode = gridOptions.api.getRowNode(event.rowIndex);
}
```

I noticed that when it calls `onCellEditingStopped`and tries to get the `rowNode` it always returns the row that was on top before I added the new row (that initial row is now the second row).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can tries the 'onCellValueChanged' instead 'onCellEditingStopped'